# Laravel FatalErrorException using multiple @include

Tags: php, laravel

```
<div id="App">
    @include('page.header', [ 'isAnimalFlag'=> in_array($page, ['animal']) ])

    @include('page.header', [ 'isInsectFlag'=> in_array($page, ['insect']) ])

    @yield('content')

    @include('page.footer')
</div>
```

Why I can't do this in laravel? Can't have multiple @include? It worked when I use just one include. How to pass multiple param then?

Comment: I think you are messing up the templates. Can you show us the controller where you create your $page array?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the extra parameters inside the first include since you are sending them both to the same partial.

```
<div id="App">
        @include('page.header', 
        [ 'isAnimalFlag'=> in_array($page, ['animal']),       
          'isInsectFlag'=> in_array($page, ['insect'])
        ])

        @yield('content')

        @include('page.footer')
    </div>
```